# Delay when coding in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am writing an GUI application using Java Swing. I just have 1 problem which is that I wrote a big function that gets executed when clicking a button. At first I am setting the value of a label to "generating report.." then just before the 'return' part of the function I set the value of the label "done generating report". What is actually happening is that the first setting of the label doesn't take effect. They both take effect after I am done with the function call so the end result just shows 'done generating report'.

Here is the java code I am using:

```
 protected void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton2ActionPerformed
        // TODO add your handling code here:

    try
    {
         jLabel6.setText("Generating Report");
         jProgressBar1.setVisible(true);
       generateReport(BillImportId.getText()); // This will take around 30 seconds to finish
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      System.out.println("Exception occured: " + e);
    }
    }//GEN-LAST:event_jButton2ActionPerformed
```

Comment: That's how it works... You are doing your operations in your UI thread, and that blocks the UI updates. Even those that are necessary to repaint the widget whose label you changed. Consider using [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) for your long-running processes.

Comment: See also [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Move the call to `generateReport` into the method `doInBackground` of a `SwingWorker`. Use the methods `process` and `done` to update your UI elements.

Check out also ["Concurrency in Swing"](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info)

Comment: I am getting this error:The method process() of type BillImportAnalyzerGUI.Task must override or implement a supertype method

Comment: I resolved my new error by asking this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245505/i-am-stuck-with-a-compilation-error-in-swing-worker So we can close this question here. Thanks a lot!